# Invert the duplicate relationship

Tags: discusión, preguntas-cerradas, pregunta-específica

I came across a duplicate question relationship which I think should be inverted.  The [closed question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16131/9385) has better answers.

From [the accepted answer in the current duplicate](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16132/1674) I like:

> It's a polite way of saying old people, and generally refers to those who are retired

and

> it's the polite way to refer to long-lived people.

While from [the accepted answer in the duplicate target](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3075/1674) I don't like:

> sinónimo de ancianidad.

---

SE Meta makes clear that an older answer can be the one to stay open, if it's more useful.  [First example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/287826):

> Usually a recent question will be closed as a duplicate of an older question, but this isn't an absolute rule. The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate.

[Second example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/287826):

> If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.
>
> You can flag and ask a moderator to merge after closure if they're exactly the same.

Comment: We all agree that it is fair to mark as principal the question having the better info. Could you also elaborate why the closed question is better? Both have similar accepted answers.

Comment: @fedorqui - I would like to follow your suggestion, but I'm having trouble, because I think it's obvious.  The only argument I can think of would be to post the better answers here, but that would be silly.

Comment: As I said, both have a similar accepted question. The *wannabe canonical* has an English and Spanish version, while the one you suggest does not. Note sure if changing the main one would be very beneficial. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @fedorqui - I like "It's a polite way of saying old people, and generally refers to those who are retired" and "it's the polite way to refer to long-lived people."  I don't like "sinónimo de ancianidad."